# Inbox notification in cq5

Tags: workflow, aem

can anyone help me out with inbox notification in cq5 . Like if a user activate a page and if in case that page goes into inbox so the user on the same page should get the notification(a popup) that he she has to go to the inbox and complete the activation of the page.

Basically I am looking a way by which I could access the inbox items in Java. So I can make a ajax call to get the relevant information and then inform the user to go to inbox and complete the workflow.

Comment: perhaps you could write a custom workflow step that sends the user an email. You would need to explore how to integrate LDAP into this, but the idea here is that the user could be notified of pending items in his CQ5 inbox via an actual email. Adding a new custom workflow step is fairly simple and covered extensively in the docs

Comment: Hi @bongman1612 thanks for the reply actually yes you got that right  that the user could be notified of pending items in his CQ5 inbox but through a pop up.Can you please put some light on the LDAP integrate.

Comment: maybe you could try this document here : http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-custom-aem-workflow-steps.html